How to keep only rows with max value in column B for each value in column A?
I have a dataframe where, for each unique system in Column A, I need to find the max date in Column B and then keep only those rows for the new dataframe. (The original dataframe contains a history of statuses for different systems and I need a dataframe with the current (most recent) status for each system.)
I've used df.groupby('System ID')['Date of Action'].max() to get a series with each System ID and the corresponding most recent Date of Action, but need a dataframe that maintains the entire rows.

